# C1 diffeomorphism with bijection and inverse function theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, jacobian

Here is the statement :
$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  Let\ \varphi :  [0,1]^{3} \rightarrow S\\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  (u,v,w)\mapsto (u(1-v) , uv(1-w) , uvw)$

where $S=\left \{  (x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^{3} : x\geqslant 0, y \geqslant 0,z \geqslant 0, x+y+z\leqslant 1 \right \}$

**a)** Show that $ \varphi$ restricted to $]0,1[^{3}$ is a $C^{1}$ diffeomorphism from $]0,1[^{3}$ to $Š=\left \{  (x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^{3} : x> 0, y> 0,z >0, x+y+z<1 \right \}$

$\textit{Indication : Show that $ \varphi$ makes a bijection and then use inverse function theorem}$.

**b)** Deduce the value of $\int \int \int_{S}\frac{1}{(1+x+y+z)^2}dxdydz$.

$$\underline{Solution}$$

*a)*
Let $(x,y,z) ∈ S$ $\Rightarrow$ $\left\{ \begin{matrix}x=u(1-v))
\\ y=uv(1-w))
\\ z=uvw
\end{matrix}\right.$

So :
$\cdot x+y+z = u-uv+uv-uvw+uvw = u ∈ ]0,1[$

$\cdot   u(1-v)=x \Rightarrow v=1-\frac{x}{x+y+z} = \frac{y+z}{x+y+z} ∈ ]0,1[$

$\cdot uv(1-w)=y \Rightarrow w=1-\frac{y}{uv} = 1 -\frac{y}{y+z} ∈ ]0,1[$

And then we see that we can write in a unique way every u,v,w so there is a bijection from $]0,1[^{3}$ to Š.

Now let's compute the Jacobian to see if it's a **local** diffeomorphism  :
$Jacobian(\varphi ')$= $\begin{pmatrix}
 1-v \ \ \ \ \   -u\ \ \ \  \  \  \  \  \  \  \   0 \\ \ \ \ 
 v(1-w) \ \    u(1-w))\ \  -uv \\ 
 vw \ \  \  \  \ \ \ \ \  uw\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ uv \\ 
\end{pmatrix}$ $\rightarrow$ det=$u^2v > 0 \ \forall \ (u,v,w) \ \in \  ]0,1[^3$.
So we have a **local** diffeomorphism + **bijection** $\rightarrow$ we have a **global** diffeomorphism !

$\\ $

*b)* :  $\int \int \int_{S}\frac{1}{(1+x+y+z)^2}dxdydz$ = $\int \int \int_{[0,1]^3}\frac{1}{(1+u)^2}*det(Jacobian(\varphi '))dudvdw$

The determinant is $u^2v$ and then :

$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{(1+u)^2}*u^2vdudvdw$ = $\int_{0}^{1}1dw\int_{0}^{1}vdv\int_{0}^{1}\frac{u^2}{(1+u)^2}du$ = $-ln(2) + \frac{3}{4}$.